# temperror when email is sent to hotmail & end up in junk/spam folder

Tags: email, hotmail, spf, dkim

When i send emails to hotmail main inboxes it ends up in spam/junk folder with the following in the header:

```
Authentication-Results : hotmail.com; spf=temperror (sender IP is X.X.X.X)
smtp.mailfrom=marieke@X.X; dkim=temperror header.d=X.com; x-hmca=none
```

However, both the Dkim and Spf are good since at least one week, and it shows "pass" when an email is sent to gmail. By the past, the domain was hosted on a different server with a different spf and dkim record in the DNS.

Is it possible that microsoft servers don't do a DNS lookup or perhaps a DNS lookup from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why it happens:

- First of all, the microsoft DNS lookup takes some time due to the TTL of DNS records, perhaps several weeks.
- Then, my mistake was to set up two A records for my smtp server hostname rather than one. Consequently due to round robin, the Forward Confirmed Reverse DNS Lookup failed from time to time as the wrong IP address was returned from time to time. Consequently if you have a smtp mail server, you should only have one A record (and one AAAA record), meaning one IP address for it.

**IPv4:**
One server hostname = Only ONE IP address (A record)
One IPv4 address = Only ONE server hostname (Reverse DNS)

**IPv6:**
One server hostname = Only ONE IP address (AAAA record)
One IPv6 address = Only ONE server hostname (Reverse DNS)

Comment: I currently have the same issue, but my TTL on the DNS is 1 day (86400), is theTTL you reference something that's Hotmail checking the DNS rather than anything you could influence?

Comment: In fact, i am sure it is not the TTL because i waited a lot. In your named.conf do you have listen-on { any; };